# Bus Error: 10 in C

Tags: c, backup, bus-error

My code compiles just fine but when I run it I get bus error: 10

```
void backupf(char *namelist, char *dirname)
{  
char    *in_filename;
char    *out_filename;
char    line[MAXPATHLEN];

FILE    *filenames = fopen(namelist, "r");

if(filenames == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot Open File\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
while( fgets(line, sizeof line, filenames) != NULL )
    {
    sprintf(in_filename, "./%s\n", line);
    sprintf(out_filename, "%s/%s\n", dirname, line);
    }
    backup(dirname, in_filename, out_filename);
fclose(filenames);
}
```

It's supposed to take a text file argument with a list of file names and then use that information to back it up to a backup directory using a backup function I've written.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Does the crash occur in `backup()` because you don't properly check that the files it uses are opened successfully? You should state what happens, and you should be able to use a debugger enough to get a stack trace so you can tell which function it crashed in (even if you can't do anything else with it). You really don't want to add newlines to the file names; you probably need to remove the newlines that `fgets()` leaves on the data it reads. And learning how to use print statements to find out what is going on is also important.

Comment: i know it crashes in the fgets() function, the backup function is fine

Comment: Odd...that tends to mean you have a buffer overflow in one of the functions this code calls.  Also odd is the fact that you don't call `backup` in the loop; you only try saving the last name that is read from the file.  It isn't clear why your `backup()` function needs the `dirname` argument.

Comment: i tried calling backup in the loop and got the same thing, so i thought i would pass the text line to a separate variable and try calling it from outside the loop. The backup function opens the backup file then copies the in_filename into the backup directory.

Comment: "i know it crashes in the fgets() function, the backup function is fine " The this should be reproducible without the `backup()` call in the code sample (and it is, as you're writing to indeterminate addresses in your pointers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't allocate space for the file names; you should.  You're writing over indeterminate memory.  This would probably work better:

```
void backupf(char *namelist, char *dirname)
{  
    char  in_filename[MAXPATHLEN];
    char  out_filename[MAXPATHLEN];
    char  line[MAXPATHLEN]; 
    FILE *filenames = fopen(namelist, "r");

    if (filenames == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot Open File\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), filenames) != NULL)
    {
        snprintf(in_filename, sizeof(in_filename)"./%s\n", line);
        snprintf(out_filename, sizeof(out_filename), "%s/%s\n", dirname, line);
        backup(dirname, in_filename, out_filename);
    }
    fclose(filenames);
}
```

Comment: @Jonathan: can you please help understand how this code is causing BUS error. which I understand occurs on unaligned access. I don't see any such thing here. Why not a segfault for this?

Comment: It isn't clear, but there's a chance that you trampled on the value in the file pointer, so it now points to an odd address, which would trigger the bus error.

Comment: ah weird. if the question is why is it giving a segmentation fault, it would've been a one word answer.